# Multiple Values for a field (Link Master fields)

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am trying to use Link Master Fields to get a value from my form in order to filter some of my data and then show the remaining on my chart. Everything works perfectly fine but when I want to select more than one value (using a listbox to select multiple values for a field), my chart returns nothing.

I would like to know how can I address multiple values for a field in my chart so it filters the values on my chart as an "Or" function in SQL.

> Imagine I want to have an SQL with: WHERE [MyTable].[Field1]= Selected values in listbox.

It seems that my SQL selects all the values in the listbox as One Value/And function.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do this via VBA.

Use the Change event on the list box to update the subforms recordsource.
Also make sure you execute the code in the forms Current event, so that it will display correctly when moving records, and on initial opening.

Answer (score 0):

So with a bit of research and trying out different ways, an easy way is to use some hidden textboxes in the form and loop through the selected values and give each textbox one of the selected values in the listbox.
From there you can write a SQL for your chart specifying the condition so your field = Condition 1 or field = Condition 2.